# Twitter Streaming Api error while while creating a connection to the remote service

Tags: java, maven, twitter-oauth, scribe, twitter-streaming-api

**Code**

```
   public abstract class TwitterStreamConsumerr {

      //  private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL ="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json";

    private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json";

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    final OAuth10aService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .apiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .apiSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .build(TwitterApi.instance());
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("=== Twitter's OAuth Workflow ===");
    System.out.println();

    // Obtain the Request Token
    System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
    final OAuth1RequestToken requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
    System.out.println("Got the Request Token!");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Now go and authorize ScribeJava here:");
    System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
    System.out.println("And paste the verifier here");
    System.out.print(">>");
    final String oauthVerifier = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
    System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
    final OAuth1AccessToken accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, oauthVerifier);
    System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
    System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken
            + ", 'rawResponse'='" + accessToken.getRawResponse() + "')");
    System.out.println();

    // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
    System.out.println("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
    final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL, service);
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
    final Response response = request.send();
    System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(response.getBody());

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("That's it man! Go and build something awesome with ScribeJava! :)");

       request.addHeader("host", "stream.twitter.com");
        request.setConnectionKeepAlive(true);
        request.addHeader("user-agent", "Twitter Stream Reader");
        request.addBodyParameter("track", "java,heroku,twitter"); // Set keywords you'd like to track here
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response1 = request.send();

        // Create a reader to read Twitter's stream
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

}

**Error**

---

### Building TwitterStreamConsumer 1.0-SNAPSHOT

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ TwitterStreamConsumer ---
=== Twitter's OAuth Workflow ===

Fetching the Request Token...
Got the Request Token!

Now go and authorize ScribeJava here:
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=S4nXCQAAAAAAji5sAAABU5p16Cg
And paste the verifier here

> > 2440695

Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...
Got the Access Token!

Now we're going to access a protected resource...
Got it! Lets see what we found...

No filter parameters found. Expect at least one parameter: follow track locations

That's it man! Go and build something awesome with ScribeJava! :)
Exception in thread "main" ***com.github.scribejava.core.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json
    at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:39)
    at com.mycompany.twitterstreamconsumer.TwitterStreamConsumerr.main(TwitterStreamConsumerr.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: connect in progress
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:517)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestMethod(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:374)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.doSend(OAuthRequest.java:45)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:37)

### ... 1 more***

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 33.684s
Finished at: Mon Mar 21 23:35:59 PKT 2016

### Final Memory: 4M/60M

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project TwitterStreamConsumer: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

**Problem**

I'm trying to get data through Twitter Streaming Api.Scribe java is used for Authentication,which is working well as you can see in the output,But Completely don't know why now it is giving error.Thanks for any help